# Storing images using node.js gives error

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, file, mediawiki

I am trying to get an image from **wikimedia** and the link of the image is

[upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e3/AybükeArslan_(3).JPG/220px-AybükeArslan_(3).JPG](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e3/Ayb%C3%BCkeArslan_(3).JPG/220px-Ayb%C3%BCkeArslan_(3).JPG)

But when i try to get the image using **node.js** the **wikimedia server** gives error statement as response. But on the browser the URL works perfectly and give the image as response.

**The is the error statement**

> 400 Bad Request The server could not comply with the request since it
>   is either malformed or otherwise incorrect. Failed to decode request

And the code is

```
var http = require('https')
  , fs = require('fs')
  , options

options = {
    host: 'upload.wikimedia.org'
  , port: 443
  , path: '/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e3/AybükeArslan_(3).JPG/220px-AybükeArslan_(3).JPG'
}


var request = http.get(options, function(res){
    var imagedata = ''
    res.setEncoding('binary')

    res.on('data', function(chunk){
        imagedata += chunk
    })

    res.on('end', function(){
       console.log(imagedata);
    })

    //trying to store the response as a jpg image which i am failing miserably because the response is a error statement rather than image stream. 
    res.on('end', function(){
        fs.writeFile('image.jpg', imagedata, 'binary', function(err){
            if (err) throw err
            console.log('File saved.')
        })
    })

})
```

Can anybody help? stuck in to it for a long time.

Comment: Question need to be moved to here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38103787/text-editor-acting-weird-cant-able-to-see-some-hidden-characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Asked a separate question to find the answer, There is some problem with hidden characters which are not visible in sublime, That causes the error, In the question the code i mentioned was completely right, For further details read below answer

[String has hidden characters, Can't able to verify ,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38103787/string-has-hidden-characters-cant-able-to-verify)

Answer (score 0):

Because you have uncoded string in url. Use `encodeURI`

**UPDATED**

```
var http = require('https')
  , fs = require('fs')
  , options;

options = {
    hostname: 'upload.wikimedia.org'
  , port: 443
  , path: encodeURI('/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e3/AybükeArslan_(3).JPG/220px-AybükeArslan_(3).JPG')
};

var request = http.get(options, function(res){
    var imagedata = '';
    res.setEncoding('binary');

    res.on('data', function(chunk){
        imagedata += chunk
    });

    res.on('end', function(){
       console.log(imagedata);
    });

    //trying to store the response as a jpg image which i am failing miserably because the response is a error statement rather than image stream. 
    res.on('end', function(){
        fs.writeFile('image.jpg', imagedata, 'binary', function(err){
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('File saved.');
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: that won't help i guess. If it works can i know the modified code

Comment: `options = {
    host: 'upload.wikimedia.org'
  , port: 443
  , path: encodeURI('/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e3/AybükeArslan_(3).JPG/220px-AybükeArslan_(3).JPG')
}`  @sivashanmugamkannan

Comment: @sivashanmugamkannan I update my answer to include code

Comment: It works , I am not sure why it did't work when i added the option you just changed before 2 comment, after i ctrl+c Ctrl+v your complete code it does, Thanks for your help any way

Comment: can you tell why added require('url') module which is not used any where in the code

Comment: I found something , The question is nothing to do with the URI encoding, This is much more weird, I found the problem related to text editor,  

Please remove encodeURI function and try the below text in your console and tell me your result.      

/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e3/AybükeArslan_(3).JPG/220px-AybükeArslan_(3).JPG

Comment: No. It is because of that characters like : ü . encoding uri solves this problem. For better understanding, you need to know `get` method calls `Url.parse` when you entered a url not options object. So call `Url.parse` with that url to that image and see results.

Comment: I edited you answer , now try the edited code and tell me your result

Comment: Without `encodeURI` it get BAD Request. When you remove encodeURI, the code is similar your initial code in question description!

Comment: But the code which i edited is working fine for me , it does't need encodeURI to work, I will reply you with my complete analysis

Comment: I ran the code with out encodeURI ,The code is running fine with out encodeURI,

Comment: I mean calling your script in console like `node index.js` or ..? I believe uri should be encoded. In your case after copy/paste my code and removing encodeURI, maybe it is because of your editor or something

Comment: As simply node index.js only ran the code, In my editor i could't able to see some hidden characters and in your editor those characters has been erased, That's why the code is working correctly, I will tell you exact reason a 15 minutes later, i will do the complete analysis and debugging for what the reason it occurs

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38103787/text-editor-acting-weird-sublime-and-c9-io-hidden-characters